# How to select values from pandas dataframe by column value

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing an analysis of a dataset with 6 classes, zero based.  The dataset is many thousands of items long.

I need two dataframes with classes 0 & 1  for the first data set and 3 & 5 for the second.

I can get 0 & 1 together easily enough:

```
mnist_01 = mnist.loc[mnist['class']<= 1]
```

However, I am not sure how to get classes 3 & 5...  so what I would like to be able to do is:

```
mnist_35 = mnist.loc[mnist['class'] == (3 or 5)]
```

...rather than doing:

```
mnist_3 = mnist.loc[mnist['class'] == 3]
mnist_5 = mnist.loc[mnist['class'] == 5]
mnist_35 = pd.concat([mnist_3,mnist_5],axis=0)
```

Comment: I guess I can do `mnist_345 = mnist.loc[mnist['class'] >= 3]`...and then `mnist_35 = mnist_345.loc[mnist['class'] != 4]`

but that is still somewhat dirty...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `isin`, probably using set membership to make each check an `O(1)` time complexity operation:

```
mnist = pd.DataFrame({'class': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                      'val': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']})

>>> mnist.loc[mnist['class'].isin({3, 5})]
   class val
3      3   d
5      5   f

>>> mnist.loc[mnist['class'].isin({0, 1})]
   class val
0      0   a
1      1   b
```

Comment: Nice, thanks--figured there was a clean way to do this.